# Arriving at the $\big(\pi_\ell,P_\ell(\mathbb{C}^2)\big)$ representation of $\mathfrak{su}(2)$

Tags: mathematical-physics, quantum-spin, group-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebra

I think I'm really close, but confused on applying the multivariable chain rule and untangling the result. The $(\Pi_\ell,P_\ell(\mathbb{C}^2))$ representation of $SU(2)$ induced from the fundamental representation $(\Pi,\mathbb{C}^2)$ is given by

$$(\Pi_\ell(A)\hspace{.5mm}p)(v)\equiv p(\Pi(A^{-1})v)=p(A^{-1}v)$$

for $A\in SU(2), v\in \mathbb{C}^2$, and $p\in P_\ell(\mathbb{C}^2)$, the set of all $\ell$ degree polynomials with basis $\{z_1^{\ell-k} z_2^k\}_{k=0}^{\ell}$. From this, we can determine the induced Lie algebra representation $(\pi_\ell,P_\ell(\mathbb{C}^2))$ of $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ from

$$(\pi_\ell(S_i)\hspace{.5mm}p)(v)=\frac{d}{dt}(\Pi_\ell(e^{tS_i})\hspace{.5mm}p)(v)|_{t=0}=\frac{d}{dt}p(e^{-tS_i}v)|_{t=0}=\sum_{j=1}^2\frac{\partial p}{\partial(e^{-tS_i}v)^j}(-S_iv)^j$$

where I'm denoting $\mathbb{C}^2$ components with $j$. This is where I'm stuck, for two reasons: **1)** not clear on how to interpret the denominator of that partial, and **2)** not clear on pulling out the representation of $\pi_\ell(S_i)$ from this $v$ dependent form.

---

**Closure:** Just wanted to take this a bit further so everything is in one place, as well as make the connection to physics. As @ACuriousMind showed, this representation is

$$\pi_\ell(S_i)=(-S_iv)_1\frac{\partial}{\partial z_1}+(-S_iv)_2\frac{\partial}{\partial z_2}$$

with $v=(z_1,z_2)^T$, so the representations of $S_k=-\frac{i}{2}\sigma_k$ become

$$\pi_\ell(S_x)=\frac{i}{2}(z_2\frac{\partial}{\partial z_1}+z_1\frac{\partial}{\partial z_2})\\\pi_\ell(S_y)=\frac{1}{2}(z_2\frac{\partial}{\partial z_1}-z_1\frac{\partial}{\partial z_2})\\\pi_\ell(S_z)=\frac{i}{2}(z_1\frac{\partial}{\partial z_1}-z_2\frac{\partial}{\partial z_2}).$$

Operating $\pi_\ell(S_z)$ on the basis $\mathcal{B}=\{z_1^{\ell-k}z_2^k\}_{k=0}^\ell$ gets

$$\pi_\ell(S_z)(z_1^{\ell-k}z_2^k) = i(\frac{\ell}{2}-k)z_1^{\ell-k}z_2^k.$$

These elements are eigenvectors, so the matrix representation in this basis has the form

$$[\pi_\ell(S_z)]_\mathcal{B}=i\pmatrix{\ell/2\\&\ell/2-1\\&&\cdot\cdot\cdot\\&&&-\ell/2}$$

and setting $s=\ell/2$ identifies this as the same form of $S_z$ acting on the Hilbert space of a spin $s$ particle. This also happens to be the same matrix form as the symmetric tensor representation $S^\ell\pi(S_z)$ on the standard basis, setting up a correspondence between symmetric $(0,\ell)$ tensors and degree $\ell$ polynomials.

Comment: Might this question be more appropriate for [math.SE]?

Comment: You're just not applying the multivariate chain rule properly. See, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Case_of_f(g1(x),_..._,_gk(x)) Also don't think of $p$ as an element in some abstract vector space with basis $z_1^{\ell-k}z_2^{k}$. It is a function of $z_1,z_2$ which themselves are functions of $t$, hence the chain rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's write the multivariate chain rule a little bit differently: With $f(t) = \mathrm{e}^{-tS_i}v$, we have

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}p(f(t))\vert_{t=0} = D_{f(0)}p \mathop{\circ} D_0f $$

where $D_x$ means the Jacobian evaluated at $x$. $D_0 f = -S_i v$ and since $f(0) = v$

$$D_{f(0)}p = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial p}{\partial z_1}, \frac{\partial p}{\partial z_2} \end{pmatrix}(v)$$

so

$$ D_{f(0)}p \mathop{\circ} D_0f = -(S_i v)_1\frac{\partial p}{\partial z_1}(v) - (S_i v)_2\frac{\partial p}{\partial z_2}(v).$$

Since the $\partial_i p$ are polynomials in $\ell - 1$-degrees and $(S_i v)_i$ is linear in $v$, this is altogether still a polynomial of degree $\ell$, so that checks out.

If you express the $(S_i v)_j$ as linear polynomials $s_{ij}(z_1,z_2)$, you get
$$ \pi_\ell(S_i) = \sum_j -s_{ij}(z_1,z_2)\frac{\partial}{\partial z_j},$$
but you can't really simplify this any further.

Comment: looks like we were doing this at the same time

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Was confusing myself with this, hadn't utilized it in a while. And I suppose, as you said, this would have been more appropriate for Mathematics.