# More efficient way to find the intertwiner $\phi$

Tags: mathematical-physics, group-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebra

I've just found the intertwiner for the fundamental and $P_1(\mathbb{C}^2)$ representations of $\mathfrak{su}(2)$, but I did it by inspection. For notation info about the $(\pi_\ell,P_\ell(\mathbb{C}^2))$ representations of $\mathfrak{su}(2)$, see my post [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/530872/arriving-at-the-big-pi-ell-p-ell-mathbbc2-big-representation-of-ma). Finding the intertwiner $\phi:P_1(\mathbb{C}^2)\rightarrow\mathbb{C}^2$ consists of solving

$$\big(\phi\hspace{1mm}\circ\hspace{1mm}\pi_1(S_k)\big)(p)=\big(S_k\hspace{1mm}\circ\hspace{1mm}\phi\big)(p),\hspace{3mm}\forall\hspace{1mm}p\in P_1(\mathbb{C}^2).$$

Looking at the $S_1$ equation for a general $p=\alpha z_1+\beta z_2$, the left and right hand sides are

$$\text{LHS}=\phi\Big[\frac{i}{2}\Big(z_2\frac{\partial}{\partial z_1}+z_1\frac{\partial}{\partial z_2}\Big)(\alpha z_1+\beta z_2)\Big]=\phi\Big[\frac{i}{2}(\alpha z_2+\beta z_1)\Big]$$

$$\text{RHS}=-\frac{i}{2}\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}\phi[\alpha z_1+\beta z_2].$$

Not really knowing how to proceed from here efficiently, I tried a few things and found

$$\phi(z_1)=\pmatrix{0\\-1},\hspace{2mm}\phi(z_2)=\pmatrix{1\\0}\hspace{3mm}\Rightarrow\hspace{3mm}\text{LHS}=\text{RHS}=\frac{i}{2}\pmatrix{\alpha\\-\beta}.$$

I won't write the other two out ($S_2$ and $S_3$), but they are also satisfied by this definition of the intertwiner. Once we go up to higher orders of $\ell$ (or any other more complicated problem), this method of just guessing the form of $\phi$ is certainly not an efficient route.

**My question:** what is a more efficient way to deduce $\phi$?

---

For example, I'm trying to find the intertwiner between the $P_2(\mathbb{C}^2)$ and adjoint representations of $\mathfrak{su}(2)$. To do this, my text mentions that you have to consider complex linear combinations of $\mathcal{B}_2=\{z_1^2,z_1z_2,z_2^2\}$ for a new basis: $\tilde{\mathcal{B}}_2=\{az_1^2+bz_1z_2,cz_1^2+dz_2^2,ez_1z_2+fz_2^2\}$, all of these constant prefactors being complex. If I were to proceed as above, I would write my general element of this vector space as

$$p=A(az_1^2+bz_1z_2)+B(cz_1^2+dz_2^2)+C(ez_1z_2+fz_2^2)\\=(Aa+Bc)z_1^2+(Ab+Ce)z_1z_2+(Bd+Cf)z_2^2.$$

Looking at the $S_1$ equation again, this would require solving

$$\phi\Big[i(Aa+Bc+Bd+Cf)z_1z_2+\frac{i}{2}(Ab+Ce)(z_1^2+z_2^2)\Big]\\=-\frac{i}{2}\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}\phi\Big[(Aa+Bc)z_1^2+(Ab+Ce)z_1z_2+(Bd+Cf)z_2^2\Big],$$

which definitely does not seem like something you'd want to go about by inspection.